# How to query FOR...IN DO in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run this query in Big Query:

```
DECLARE
  tables ARRAY<STRING>;
SET
  tables = ['table1',
  'table2',
  'table3']; FOR loop_variable_name IN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(tables)) DO 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  FORMAT("""SELECT * FROM dataset.%s WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '2023-06-22' LIMIT 10""", loop_variable_name);
END
  FOR;
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error:

`Invalid type for argument 2 to FORMAT; Expected STRING; Got STRUCT<f0_ STRING> at [14:23]`

How can I pass the tables as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#for-in):

> On each iteration, the value of `loop_variable_name` is a `STRUCT` that contains the top-level columns of the table expression as fields.

You can consider below instead.

```sql
DECLARE tables ARRAY<STRING>;
SET tables = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3'];

FOR loop_variable_name IN (
  SELECT tbl_name FROM UNNEST(tables) tbl_name
) DO 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  FORMAT("""
    SELECT * FROM dataset.%s
     WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '2023-06-22' LIMIT 10
  """, loop_variable_name.tbl_name);
END
FOR;
```

- Added `tbl_name` as a column alias in the `IN` subquery. You can access it as a field of `STRUCT` like `loop_variable_name.tbl_name` in your dynamic sql statement.